# xsl - grouping nodes based on attributes between 2 nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

In XSL 1.0, I have had a search and have found similar items around grouping but I think this is slightly different. *Apologies if this has already been covered I haven't been able to find the answer*

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xmldoc>
<section paragraphMarker="true">Part 1. </section>
<section paragraphMarker="false">Part 2. </section>
<section paragraphMarker="false">Part 3. </section>
<section paragraphMarker="true">Part 4. </section>
<section paragraphMarker="true">Part 5. </section>
<section paragraphMarker="false">Part 6. </section>
</xmldoc>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<p>Part 1. Part 2. Part 3.</p>
<p>Part 4. </p>
<p>Part 5. Part 6. </p>
```

I have tried the following:-

```
<xsl:key name="sectionsWithParagraphMarker" 
    match="section[@paragraphMarker='true']" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select=
    "/xmldoc/section[generate-id()
         = 
    generate-id(key('sectionsWithParagraphMarker',.)[1])]">
   <p>
<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="./following-sibling::node()
         [count(. | /xmldoc/section[@paragraphMarker='true'][1]/
             preceding-sibling::node())
         =
         count(/xmldoc/section[@paragraphMarker='true'][1]/
             preceding-sibling::node())
         ]"/>  
        </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:select value-of="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

This isn't working and I have got stuck with it. It's selecting too many 'section' nodes for all groups. Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and more efficient (key-based) solurion. Explanation is also provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <xsl:if test="@paragraphMarker='true'">
            <p>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="text" />
            </p>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section" mode="text">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::section[1][@paragraphMarker='false']" mode="text" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Since this code only looks forward, it is much more efficient than a solution doing backtracking (the XPath axes which are going backwards are slow in many implementations).

Comment: I don't know why - but this is the only one that works for me from my ant script... Thanks @Lucero

Comment: "Since this code only looks forward, it is much more efficient than a solution doing backtracking (the XPath axes which are going backwards are slow in many implementations)". Before this turns into an urban myth, can you cite any evidence? I suspect that following-sibling::x[1] and preceding-sibling::x[1] have identical performance in most implementations - it's the [1] that makes the difference, not the preceding/following distinction. It's possible that your statement is correct for some implementations but it would be nice to have evidence.

Comment: For instance the .NET XML classes are single-linked lists (see for instance `XmlLinkedNode` and `XContainer`), with a reference to the next item only. Whenever you request the previous node it starts by traversing all nodes starting with the first child of the parent. I'm sure that this holds for other DOM-based implementations as well; most APIs are optimized to start with the first child and then traverse it in an advancing manner.

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kSectsByPara"
  match="section[not(@paragraphMarker='true')]"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*
                    [@paragraphMarker='true']
                    [1]
                   )"
 />

 <xsl:template match="*[@paragraphMarker='true']">
  <p>
   <xsl:copy-of select=
    "text()|key('kSectsByPara', generate-id())/text()"/>
  </p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*[not(@paragraphMarker='true')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<xmldoc>
    <section paragraphMarker="true">Part 1. </section>
    <section paragraphMarker="false">Part 2. </section>
    <section paragraphMarker="false">Part 3. </section>
    <section paragraphMarker="true">Part 4. </section>
    <section paragraphMarker="true">Part 5. </section>
    <section paragraphMarker="false">Part 6. </section>
</xmldoc>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<p>Part 1. Part 2. Part 3. </p>
<p>Part 4. </p>
<p>Part 5. Part 6. </p>
```

**Explanation**:

The `<xsl:key>` named "kSectsByPara" defines the mapping between a `generate-id()` of a `section` having attribute `paragraphMarker="true"` and the group of following `section` elements that have their attribute `paragraphMarker="false"` .

Comment: +1 for the more efficient solution, which should be used for large inputs.

Comment: @lwburk, since the computation of the key also takes some time (and space) it may well be that this solution is less efficient on large sets than mine. One would have to banchmark it on the specific target XSLT engine in order to get meaningful results.

Comment: thanks @Dimitre Novachev, for some reason for me, with this stylesheet this isn't working from my ant script; though again it gives the correct result from Firefox + adddon...

Comment: @MrChick: You are welcome. I have no experience with using XSLT from Ant -- maybe they have a non-compliant XSLT processor, or one that needs to be further configured.

Comment: got it working     `<xslt basedir="${temp.dir}" classpath="${basedir}/lib/xalan.jar" destdir="${html.output.dir}"
      extension=".html" style="${style.dir}/DN_CreateHTML.xsl">
        <factory name="org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl" />` also when I re-copied and pasted your answer and when using the new transformer It complained _There is no xsl:key declaration for kSectsByPara_ the key is defined as _kSectsByPara_ once I made these both the same it worked fine - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="section[@paragraphMarker='true']">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates
               select=".|following-sibling::section[not(@paragraphMarker='true')]
           [preceding-sibling::section[@paragraphMarker='true'][1]=current()]" 
               mode="inner"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="section" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces the desired output:

```
<p>Part 1. Part 2. Part 3. </p>
<p>Part 4. </p>
<p>Part 5. Part 6. </p>
```

In English, we're selecting all of the following siblings that are not a paragraph marker and whose first preceding sibling that *is* a paragraph marker is the *current* marker. Note that this requires us to move through all of the following siblings and then backtrack to look for the previous marker (in each case).

Comment: thanks again for the fast response, I have tried your stylesheet with my input file but don't appear to be getting any output?? could this be anything to do with the technology I am using??

Comment: @MrChick - I just copy/pasted your source XML and my answer and tried it again. It's working fine for me. Are you using it as part of a larger stylesheet? Might be other templates interfering.

Comment: I've removed everything else from my stylesheet. I am using java/ant with a style tag in the build file to invoke the stylesheet??

Comment: Just copied/pasted both files (input and stylesheet) again and re-run - now getting:-
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>Part 1. Part 2. Part 3. Part 6. </p>


<p>Part 4. </p>
<p>Part 5. </p>', any ideas?

Comment: @MrChick - I have run this in Saxon 9B and using Firefox. Worked in both places. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks @lwburk I have run just now with Firefox + "Perform XSL transformation" Add-on and it appears to be working there... Will have to take a deeper look at what is causing the difference of opinion.

C:\dev\Simple\createOutput>ant -verbose convertHTML
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: C:\dev\Simple\createOutput\build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.6 in: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre
Detected OS: Windows XP 

convertHTML:
     [xslt] Using class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison